# How to add external module to a gradle project in Intellij IDEA 14?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, module

I extracted some part of my code and resources to a new local module in Intellij IDEA 14, because the copies of them are used in several projects. I want to use the module as a support module for my gradle projects.

When the project is not based on gradle, module could be added to my project easily by adding dependency in 'project structure'. But it doesn't work in a gradle project.

How can I use the code and resources from my local module in a gradle project?

What should I do for the support module and my gradle project? I've read the user guide of gradle but still can't find a solution.

UPDATE: below is the project structure

```
External Gradle project
--external_project
----lib
--------src
--------build.gradle
----settings.gradle

Current Gradle project    
--current_project
----app
--------src
--------build.gradle
----settings.gradle
```

I'm getting a error message when gradle builds,
`Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can link any module by full path

1) Add module in your project `settings.gradle`

```
include ':app', ':mylib'
project(':mylib').projectDir = new File("/path-to-project/external_project/lib")
```

2) Add dependency in `build.gradle` of `app` module

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mylib')
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But i got a error msg, ` Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.` And what should the 'mylocalmodule' be, the path of module, its package name or project folder name? The code I add in build.gradle is `compile project(':com.example.mylocalmodule.lib')`

Comment: thank you again but I'm still getting the same error. I've updated my project structure in my question above. The `app` and `mylocalmodule` are not at same level.

Comment: @ProtossShuttle Is it two idea projects? Or module lib is inside module mylocalmodule?

Comment: `mylocalmodule` is a stand-alone project, the code and resources of which is in the subfolder `lib`. `mylocalmodule` and `currentworkingmodule` are in different folders.

Comment: @ProtossShuttle i updated question and answer. please try again

Comment: Hello. Trying to use your suggestion. Gradle complains: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'projectDir' for project 'name-of-project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.